# How to export Microsoft 365 group owners from local PowerShell script

Tags: active-directory, powershell, microsoft-office-365

My company uses Microsoft 365. When I go to admin.microsoft.com, I can see "Teams & groups > Active teams & groups" as navigation item.

Opening one of the groups in the side panel, I can see "Owners" and "Members" as distinct sublists within the "Membership" tab:

[image: The "Owners" list of a group in Microsoft 365 admin center]

[image: The "Members" list of a group in Microsoft 365 admin center]

I want to retrieve the member lists of all groups, alongside the information whether each member is an owner, using a PowerShell script, from my local PC. Ultimately, I want to export that to CSV, but for now I'm just print-lining to the host. This is my latest attempt:

```
Connect-MsolService
$Groups = Get-MsolGroup -GroupType DistributionList
foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $GroupName = $Group.DisplayName
    $Address = $Group.EmailAddress
    $GroupId = $Group.ObjectId
    $Group2 = Get-MsolGroup -ObjectId $GroupId
    $ManagedBy = $Group2.ManagedBy
    $GroupMembers = Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $GroupId
    $Fields = $GroupName, $Address, $GroupId, $ManagedBy.EmailAddress + $GroupMembers.EmailAddress
    $Content = $Fields -join ','
    $Content
}
```

The result this gives me is this (notice how the 4th column that should be the `$ManagedBy.EmailAddress` is empty):

```
Foo,foo@example.org,085d1225-a545-e497-b37b-c6496da4fedd,,chuck.doe@example.org,frank.doe@example.org,alice.doe@example.org,david.doe@example.org,bob.doe@example.org,erin.doe@example.org
```

There are several things I changed from the original draft before arriving here:

First, I tried to use `$GroupMembers.GroupMemberType` to differentiate between "Owner" and "Member", but the possible values of this property are "User, ServicePrincipal, Contact, or Group", so it is `User` for members and owners alike, and clearly was not how to do it.

Next, I tried to access `$Group.ManagedBy`, hoping to identify at least *one* of the owners for a start. But the property was empty. [Some Microsoft Community Hub post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/the-managedby-is-not-populating-with-the-get-msolgroup-command/m-p/67636) suggested this was because `ManagedBy` was only filled when the request was for a single object, hence the `$Group2` query and the current form of the script. However, the `$ManagedBy` variable is still **always** empty, for all groups.

So how can I access the information whether a member is an owner, information that the online admin portal obviously has access to?

---

### Additional info:

I also tried to use `Get-ADGroup` from the `ActiveDirectory` module after enabling RSAT, but this one never asks for or finds a way to connect to the online resource, and the only thing I could find was a supposed `Connect-ADServer` cmdlet which isn't recognized as a valid cmdlet on my machine (`Get-ADGroup` is, though). Not sure if all that is only meant to be used on the AD server or in the cloud shell.

What further complicates my situation is that according to the [Microsoft Learn documentation of `MSOnline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/msonline) it is deprecated, so it recommends "[Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview)" (not sure if that's the same as the `ActiveDirectory` module), which according to itself is **also** already deprecated, hence *that* is referring to yet another thing, namely [`Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/microsoftgraph/overview), which doesn't really look like cmdlets but rather like .NET libraries (but I might be wrong).

It also doesn't help that `PowerShell ISE` is also deprecated and everything is a horrible mess in outdated information with deprecation notes linking to also deprecated replacements. I am totally confused and don't even know anymore whether a fixed script using `Get-MsolGroup` would work for more than 3 months.

So, I started my quest with "How to get the member role" and have now been down a 10 hour rabbit hole ending up at "What module in which IDE can I even use that isn't deprecated in a few months?"

Comment: You're looking for Microsoft Graph PowerShell Module -- but honestly, its crap - its a bunch of autogenerated cmdlets based on autorest/swagger/openapi -- with no though put into them at all for the end-conumser of the module.  IN some cases its as if the pipeline was never invented.  You're almost better off just learning to use powershell (or something else) to read/write the API natively.  I digress.

The module can be installed from the gallery (Microsoft.Graph) https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph/2.12.0

Comment: Okay, so the deprecation-redirect-cascade was leading the right way. But oh my god. After installing the module, PowerShell autocomplete has become useless, because for every prefix like Add-, Find-, Get- etc. there's now 50 -MgSomething suggestions. Ugh. You know what, before I figure out how to find the right union of permissions for the 60 cmdlets necessary to get the data, I might as well go through the groups panels in 365 online admin panel, and write down the owners by hand. Sadly I'm afraid that is faster, even for the 90 groups we have.

Comment: Those groups are all Microsoft 365 groups when you look in Entra?

Answer (score 0):

I would install vscode on my machine, and use the graph module.
For getting the owners you could something like this, how you get the members that's something I let you figure out yourself

```
# Install and import the Microsoft Graph PowerShell module
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph -Force -AllowClobber
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph

# Authenticate to Microsoft Graph (you will be prompted to sign in)
Connect-MgGraph

# Get all Microsoft 365 groups
$groups = Get-MgGroup -Top 500 # You can adjust 'Top' based on your needs

# Iterate through each group and display owners
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $groupId = $group.Id
    $owners = Get-MgGroupOwner -GroupId $groupId
    Write-Host "Owners of group '$($group.DisplayName)': $($owners.UserPrincipalName -join ', ')"
}

# Disconnect from Microsoft Graph
Disconnect-MgGraph
```

Comment: I had been using VS Code, too. `Get-MgGroupOwner` is not quite what I need, because it only has the Ids. I tried `Get-MgGroupOwnerAsUser` and that was better, `Get-MgGroupMemberAsUser` doesn't work though. I get the right number of objects, but all their properties except for their Ids are always `null`, even with `-Property` defined. Needs more try and error, or I'll forgo the PS approach and try my luck with the C# SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Microsoft Teams module

```
# Install the required module if not already installed
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -Force -AllowClobber

# Connect to Microsoft 365
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

# Get all Microsoft 365 groups
$groups = Get-Team

# Loop through each group
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    # Get group details
    $groupDetails = Get-TeamUser -GroupId $group.GroupId

    # Output group name
    Write-Host "Group: $($groupDetails.DisplayName)"

    # Loop through group members
    foreach ($member in $groupDetails) {
        $isOwner = if ($member.Role -eq "Owner") { "Owner" } else { "Member" }
        Write-Host "  Member: $($member.User.DisplayName), Role: $isOwner"
    }

    # Add a separator for better readability
    Write-Host "-----------------------"
}

# Disconnect from Microsoft 365
Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams
```